# O que seria equivalente a essas duas propriedades do persistence.xml no hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, eclipse-link

Tenho essas duas propriedades no eclipselink :

```
  <property name="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="FINE"/>
   <property name="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="true"/>
```

mas gostaria de ver o mesmo usando o **hibernate**.

Aqui esta o meu arquivo de persistência:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="TestePstgresqlJPA-PU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>br.com.k19.modelos.Autor</class>
        <class>br.com.k19.modelos.Editora</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/EJB3_Banco"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="123456"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.schema-generation.database.action" value="create"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

Estou usando o maven e abaixo esta o POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>TestelJPA</groupId>
    <artifactId>TestelJPA</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.1207</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <name>TestelJPA</name>
</project>
```

Venho trabalhando com o eclipse link a alguns meses mas com o hibernate sou ainda um leigo, neste POM esta tudo certo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja se Resolve:

```
<property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
```

Comment: Que estranho, eu uso essas propriedades e funciona normal, exibe as sql geradas e formatadas no console. tentou dar um build no projeto?

Comment: Poste o seu arquivo persistence.xml pra dar uma olhada.

Comment: Deu certo, mas surgiu outro problema!!!    
Quando crio uma classe Editora e Autor e persisto tudo ok! Mas quando depois de ter executado isso , por exemplo eu uso o find Editora , e executo o projeto ele  retorna uma exceção: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "autor" already exists  . Pode me ajudar?

Comment: Que bom que funcionou :), Creio que deva abrir outro tópico para detalhar esse problema, assim fica mais fácil encontrar uma solução para ele.